# Python compare 2 files line by line. if line from file 1 is not in line from file 2, then print

Tags: python, string, compare

I have been using the next code to read line by line, file1 and search if any line of file2 contains this line. Then print it.

```
import os
import sys

def extractAllLine(str2Search):
    with open("/path/to/dump/file/Dump.txt") as All_file:
       for line in All_file:
            if str2Search in line:
               print line,

def extractFilter():
    with open("/path/to/filter/Filter.txt") as filter_file:
        for line in filter_file:
            filterstring = line.rstrip()
            extractAllLine(filterstring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractFilter()
```

Dump.txt

```
brandon richardson
kian dixon
ashton harris
jamie hunt
reece thomas
kendrick battle
tucker blankenship
jamie holman
mitchell douglas
ace holder
```

Filter.txt

```
jamie
dixon
ace
```

running code will result:

```
jamie hunt
jamie holman
kian dixon
ace holder
```

now I want to do the inverse, I want to print lines from file2 that does not contain line from file1.
example:

Dump.txt and Filter.txt, keep the same.
But wished result would be:

```
brandon richardson
ashton harris
reece thomas
kendrick battle
tucker blankenship
mitchell douglas
```

I tried changing "if" in def extracAllLine:

```
if str2Search **not** in line:
   print line,
```

but it does not work.
How can I change this to false so I can get the wanted result.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse condition for not search key words in your `filter.txt` should be

```
jamie not in line and dixon not in line and ace not in line ...
```

So you should get all these key words first.

Here's a simply example for refenrence, you can do it in your way.

```
import os
import sys

def extractAllLine(strsNot2Search):
    with open("/path/to/filter/Dump.txt") as All_file:
       for line in All_file:
            if not list(filter(lambda str2Search: str2Search in line, strsNot2Search)):
                print(line)


def extractFilter():
    with open("/path/to/filter/Filter.txt") as filter_file:
        filterConditions = []  # collect all your not search conditions here
        for line in filter_file:
            filterstring = line.rstrip()
            filterConditions.append(filterstring)
        extractAllLine(filterConditions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractFilter()
```

Comment: Perfect!, I thought it was needed a "not in" only to reverse the search. But I see it takes more than that. I'm curious you said "do it in your way", is there any other solution more effective than comparing lines? a faster solution or faster algorithm?